# Error running Azure Powershell task: Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have a release pipeline that contains an **Azure Powershell** task, which was configured to run on a particular agent pool that has **private** build agents. Task was running fine until a few days ago when it started failing with the following error:

> Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription

At first I thought it could be an error related to the script being executed in the task, but then I realized any command running on an **Azure Powershell** task was failing - even a basic command like this:

[image: Azure Powershell task]

**The task runs successfully when using other build agents installed in a different VM**. Also, the task was configured to use v2 and the latest version of Powershell installed.

These are some of the things I've tried, without success:

- Use task v3 (same error)
- Use task v4 (different error)
- Running the task with a specific Powershell version (e.g. 5.7.0)
- Use other Azure subscriptions

What am I missing here?

Unfortunately SO doesn't allow me to paste here the full log of the task (in debug mode), so I'll paste here the lines where the error occurred:

```
##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
##[command]Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave -ErrorAction Stop
##[command]Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
##[command] Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId b6689fdb-ac8c-4116-8136-c7a179cb5be6 -TenantId ***
##[debug]Leaving Initialize-Azure.
##[debug]Importing function 'CmdletHasMember'.
##[debug]Importing function 'Disconnect-AzureAndClearContext'.
##[debug]Importing function 'Initialize-AzModule'.
##[debug]Importing function 'Initialize-Azure'.
##[debug]Importing function 'Initialize-AzureRMModule'.
##[debug]Importing function 'Remove-EndpointSecrets'.
##[debug]Trying to disconnect from Azure and clear context at process scope
##[command]Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
##[debug]Error record:
##[debug]Select-AzureRMSubscription : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
##[debug]At F:\Agent03\w\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\2.153.1\ps_modules\VstsAzureHelpers_\InitializeFunctions.ps1:372 char:17
##[debug]+ ...     $null = Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionI ...
##[debug]+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmContext], ArgumentEx    ception
##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMConte    xtCommand
##[debug] 
##[debug]Script stack trace:
##[debug]at Set-CurrentAzureRMSubscription, F:\Agent03\w\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\2.153.1\ps_modules\VstsAzureHelpers_\InitializeFunctions.ps1: line 372
##[debug]at Initialize-AzureSubscription, F:\Agent03\w\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\2.153.1\ps_modules\VstsAzureHelpers_\InitializeFunctions.ps1: line 248
##[debug]at Initialize-Azure, F:\Agent03\w\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\2.153.1\ps_modules\VstsAzureHelpers_\VstsAzureHelpers_.psm1: line 58
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, F:\Agent03\w\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\2.153.1\AzurePowerShell.ps1: line 78
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
##[debug]Exception:
##[debug]System.ArgumentException: Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.SetCurrentContext(String subscriptionNameOrId, String tenantId, String name)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand.<>c__DisplayClass37_1.<ExecuteCmdlet>b__2(AzureRmProfile profile, RMProfileClient client, String name)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Common.AzureContextModificationCmdlet.ModifyContext(Action`2 contextAction)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand.SetContextWithOverwritePrompt(Action`3 setContextAction)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
##[debug]   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
##[error]Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
```

List of Az* powershell installed are the following:

```
Name                                  Version   
----                                  -------   
Azure                                 5.1.2     
Azure.AnalysisServices                0.5.4     
Azure.Storage                         4.6.1     
AzureRM                               6.13.1    
AzureRM.AnalysisServices              0.6.14    
AzureRM.ApiManagement                 6.1.7     
AzureRM.ApplicationInsights           0.1.8     
AzureRM.Automation                    6.1.1     
AzureRM.Backup                        4.0.11    
AzureRM.Batch                         4.1.5     
AzureRM.Billing                       0.14.6    
AzureRM.Cdn                           5.0.6     
AzureRM.CognitiveServices             0.9.12    
AzureRM.Compute                       5.9.1     
AzureRM.Consumption                   0.3.7     
AzureRM.ContainerInstance             0.2.12    
AzureRM.ContainerRegistry             1.0.10    
AzureRM.DataFactories                 5.0.3     
AzureRM.DataFactoryV2                 0.5.11    
AzureRM.DataLakeAnalytics             5.1.4     
AzureRM.DataLakeStore                 6.2.1     
AzureRM.DevTestLabs                   4.0.9     
AzureRM.Dns                           5.1.0     
AzureRM.EventGrid                     0.3.7     
AzureRM.EventHub                      0.7.0     
AzureRM.HDInsight                     4.1.8     
AzureRM.Insights                      5.1.5     
AzureRM.IotHub                        3.1.8     
AzureRM.KeyVault                      5.2.1     
AzureRM.LogicApp                      4.1.4     
AzureRM.MachineLearning               0.18.5    
AzureRM.MachineLearningCompute        0.4.8     
AzureRM.MarketplaceOrdering           0.2.7     
AzureRM.Media                         0.10.4    
AzureRM.Network                       6.11.1    
AzureRM.NotificationHubs              5.0.3     
AzureRM.OperationalInsights           5.0.6     
AzureRM.PolicyInsights                1.1.0     
AzureRM.PowerBIEmbedded               4.1.10    
AzureRM.Profile                       4.6.0     
AzureRM.profile                       5.8.2     
AzureRM.RecoveryServices              4.1.9     
AzureRM.RecoveryServices.Backup       4.5.2     
AzureRM.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery 0.2.12    
AzureRM.RedisCache                    5.1.0     
AzureRM.Relay                         0.3.12    
AzureRM.Resources                     6.7.3     
AzureRM.Scheduler                     0.16.10   
AzureRM.ServerManagement              4.1.2     
AzureRM.ServiceBus                    0.6.13    
AzureRM.ServiceFabric                 0.3.15    
AzureRM.SignalR                       1.0.0     
AzureRM.SiteRecovery                  5.0.6     
AzureRM.Sql                           4.12.1    
AzureRM.Storage                       5.2.0     
AzureRM.StreamAnalytics               4.0.10    
AzureRM.Tags                          4.0.5     
AzureRM.TrafficManager                4.1.3     
AzureRM.UsageAggregates               4.0.5     
AzureRM.Websites                      5.2.0
```

Comment: What Azure PowerShell modules are installed? `Get-Module Az*` And you're sure that the service principal you're using still has access to the subscription?

Comment: @DanielMann edited my question - I've used command `Get-InstalledModule`, not `Get-Module`. Regarding the principal, I do believe it has access to the subscription - the task runs successfully when using another build agent/VM.

Comment: Could you please try to re-install the agent in this machine, Also try to Add SubscriptionId in Add-AzureRMAccount method along with tenant id in GUID format.

Comment: @MohitVerma re-installing the agent is something I'd do only as a last resort. Not sure if I understand what you mean by '_Add SubscriptionId in Add-AzureRMAccount_'? Where should I do that? The service endpoint (Azure subscription) used in the task is working correctly

Comment: I see , you have called Add-AzureRMAccount in powershell 5.7 which is not available : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/add-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-4.4.1&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-5.7.0 Additionally i would suggest you to use Get-AzureRmSubscription instead if Select-AzureRMSubscription Please try to modify and see if it works.

Comment: @MohitVerma you're missing the point - I'm not invoking `Select-AzureRMSubscription` _manually_, that is done by the `Azure Powershell` task

Comment: ah okay, let me check then and see if i am able to reproduce it.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT using hosted agents is not an option in my case.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT sure, I didn't post the full log because of SO's limitations. What's the best way to send it to you?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT email was sent, many thanks for your assistance